# How to implement IFC files 3d viewing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d-modelling, ifc

I need to open .ifc file in iOS. Besides, I need to allow user to go with different action like pan, zoom and other gesture need to be implemented. I found some libraries to implement IFC in iOS such as IFCPLusPLus, Revit, IFC SDK and all. But they don't have documentation. And library has .cpp extension classes. So if anyone knows how to implement iFC files 3d viewing in iOS, please help..